# Resnick's A Probability Path Exercise 10.7

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose that X1, X2 are i.i.d. exponential random variables with mean 1, i.e., their densities are given by $e^{-x}$ for x > 0. Compute

1. $E[X_1|X_1 + X_2]$.
2. $P(X-1 < 3|X-1 + X-2)$.
3. $E[X-1| \min(X-1, t)]$.
4. $E[X-1| \max(X1, t)]$.

My work:For the first one, I think since $X_1$ is measurable on $\sigma(X_1+X_2)$ then $E[X_1|X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]$. And this imply that $X_1$ is independent to $X_1 + X_2$, which is not make sense. I am wondering where I am wrong here.

Comment: $X_1$ is not measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(X_1+X_2)$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy Could you give me more explanation that $X_1$ is not  is not measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(X_1+X_2)$

Comment: You are mistaking $\sigma (X_1+X_2)$ for $\sigma (X_1,X_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

> My work:For the first one

My solution for the first one

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_1+X_2]+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1+X_2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1+X_2|X_1+X_2]=x_1+x_2$$

As per independence the rv are also exchangeable, thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_1+X_2]=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$

Comment: I supposed the the part 1 asked for a r.v. to estimate the $E[X_1|X_1+X_2]$ instead of given a number $t, X_1+X_2=t$

Comment: @Andy Jihn : nothin changes. Edited